# Visual studio - Debugging app with word API is impossible

Tags: visual-studio-2008, api, ms-word

I have an application which uses the MS-Word API.
I get stuck when trying to use the function Document.Open(Filename) which is the function that is opening a document.
It doesn't matter if I run in debug or release mode.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you,
Guy Marom

Comment: Some more information would be helpful. Can you post a copy of your code, and an error messages?

Comment: What do you mean by, "I get stuck"? Exactly what happens (or doesn't happen that you expect to)?

Comment: If I put a breakpoint on this line:
Dim objDoc As Word.Document = mobjWordApp.Documents.Open(CObj(FileName))
When I hit F10, nothing happens and no exception is thrown.
mobjWordApp is instantiated as so: mobjWordApp = new Interop.Word.Application.
The first line is performed in a different thread.

Comment: Can you open the document in question manually in Word? Word displays a modal dialog box for certain documents (e.g. macro security warnings) which will block the execution. Please note that Word is not intended to be used in a non-interactive environment.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch more paramters you need for the Open method!

```
object fileName = "MyDocuemnt.docx";
object readOnly = false;
object isVisible = true;
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
WordApp.Visible = true;
Word.Document aDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing,ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible);
aDoc.Activate();
```

The Word (and Office) API from .Net requires all paramters as opposed to VBA, hence the long line of missing's

It's a pain, but you can make some wrapper classes to hide this from your main application logic if the solution is to become large and complex

Comment: 1) The code runs fine if I run it as a windows service on my machine.
2) I don't want my document to be visible so I set:
   WordApp.Visible = False
   isVisibile = False

Comment: You shoudln't run Word as part of a windows service (see MSDN). What are you trying to do? The visible bit is of course optional :-)

Comment: I have several applications using word automation:
1) The service - Sends DOC/DOCX files to the printer.
2) A word add-in that uses automation to explore a mail merge datasource.

I just noticed that these problems are related to the fact that I use word in a different thread than the main thread.